# Get Duration of Media Before Playing

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a `QMediaPlayer` object, which if I try to get the duration of before letting the file buffer enough, will return `-1`. To my understanding, this is because the file is loaded asynchronously and duration (and subsequently position) cannot be known since it is unknown if the file is fully loaded yet.

My initial idea to solve this was to run `media.play()`, immediately followed by `media.stop()`. This does absolutely nothing. Then, I considered running `media.play()` and `media.pause().` This does not work either. I imagine this is because the media needs to buffer for a significant period of time before the duration can be obtained. Also, this "solution" would not have been ideal regardless.

How can I get the duration of a QMediaPlayer object before the file has been played?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the [`durationChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#durationChanged) signal:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot('qint64')
    def on_durationChanged(duration):
        print(duration)
        player.stop()
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    player.durationChanged.connect(on_durationChanged)
    file = "/path/of/small.mp4"
    player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
    player.play()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```